# Design Mode Preprocessor Directive Workaround

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, preprocessor, design-time

I know that there is no DESIGN, DESIGN_MODE, DESIGN_TIME, etc preprocessor directive value. However, I need something that can do the trick. I can't use a normal If statement, because in my case I need to change the inherited class so that the control renders properly at design time. If not, I'll receive an exception due to the fact that the inherited class is an abstract class.

Here's what I'm looking to accomplish:

```
Partial Class MyCustomControl
#If DesignMode Then
       Inherits UserControl
#Else
    Inherits WidgetControl
#End If
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can't make this work.  You'll have to make your base class a non-abstract class to support design time.

Comment: But I'm sure there's a way around it without needing a non-abstract class. I've even tried creating an intermediary class that inherits from WidgetControl, but then when I'm debugging and/or releasing, I want to use WidgetControl. There's got to be a way to use a preprocessor directive.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
if (this.DesignMode == true)
{    }
else
{    }
```

Comment: The 'this' refers to the current class which inherits from a UserControl.

Comment: How can I use this with inheritance? I'm pretty sure I can't.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I have created a dummy class as a go between.  Sometimes VS will still figure out what you are doing and get upset, but normally restarting the IDE will solve that.

```
Partial Class MyCustomControl : MyAbstractClass_FAKE_IMPL
{
  //your normal class
}
```

and

```
Partial Class MyAbstractClass_FAKE_IMPL : MyAbstractClass
{

  //let IDE autogenerate implementation code that you are always going to override in reality.

}
```